# Website scroll depth analysis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am working on a website scroll depth analysis tool.

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to calculate the depth where reached 80/60/40/20 percent of visitors.

A Solution I have now:

data:

*Each data point represents lowest reach point in the session (px), one data point is one session*

```
500
500
520
521
545---80%
545
545
545
545
545---60%
595
600
645
684
775---40%
850
850
876
896
920---20%
934
1000
1008
1045
1169
```

So the logic is that the value at 20% is where 80% reach.

Now, with this logic it can happen that 80% and 60% have the same value, does it make sense?

Is there a better logic here?

Comment: Yes it makes sense if you have ties.